# Nicely formatted logs in GNOME's Empathy IM client

Tags: gnome, logs, gnome3, empathy

I am using empathy, and every time I want to browse my logs I have to do this for instance (`ag` is a sort of `grep`, if you are wondering):

```
cd ~/.local/share/TpLogger/logs/
ag "myterm"
cat myuser/chatrooms/#chatroom/20150409.log
```

This is *absolutely* insane; not least of all because the logs are formatted xml style - so I either have to parse them instead of just using `cat` or try to read between the tags.

Does empathy *really* have no log viewer?

Comment: I don't use `empathy` (it's not installed on my system) but according to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663873) it should have a "log viewer"... try `empathy-logs` in terminal...

Comment: sadly no such command. I also don't think it is in a separate package (and certainly it should not be).

Comment: Apparently, it used to [be included in `empathy` package](http://manned.org/empathy-logs/ca5d8fc7) but tbh, I wouldn't know. As I said, I am not familiar at all with `empathy`.